# Kohler shower mixing valve cartridge replacement

Tags: mixing-valve

I'm struggling to figure out what cartridge goes with this mixing valve assembly. The trim is Kohler T161117-4A-CP-FB which is discontinued. I assume this doesn't necessarily mean that the cartridge replacement for the mixing valve is discontinued or does it? Any advice or direction is much appreciated.

The stamped date in blue is August 2012.

Using the Kohler identifying tool- I can only find a black plastic cap rather than a white one like shown below.

Without square adapter
[image: Text]

With square adapter
[image: Text]

Comment: Call Kohler's customer service line. They'll be able to identify it fron a few pics.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two screws on the white part. Once you remove it you will see it a regular black Kohler cartridge.